# Applying function to subsamples defined by multiple dimensions

Tags: r

My data frame looks something like the following example

```
dd <- read.table(text="ID   SIZR   COLOUR   COUNTRY  VALUE
1    Small  Green    Canada   1
2    Large  Green    USA      1
3    Large  Green    Canada   1   
4    Small  Black    USA      2   
5    Medium Black    Canada   3   
6    Medium Black    Canada   3   
7    Medium Black    Canada   3   
8    Small  White    Canada   7   ", header=T)
```

I want to compute the mean values for all subsamples that can be formed by grouping the observations based on all possible combinations of the data frames different variables, like SIZE and COLOUR

```
      Small   Medium  Large
Black 2       3       NA
Green 1       NA      1
White 7       NA      NA
```

How do I apply the mean-function to all the different subsamples resulting from combining the two vectors SIZE (Small, Medium, Large) and COLOUR (Black, Green, White) without having to define the subsamples manually?

I feel like one of the apply-functions might be of help, but I can't figure out how to get the result above.

And: is there a way to extend this matrix by a third/fourth/fifth) dimension (like COUNTRY)?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. It's hard to include an example, but I edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: I feel like the apply-family could be useful here, I'm just not sure which one.

Comment: I re-edited by question. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Something like `with(dd, tapply(VALUE, list(COLOUR, SIZR), FUN=mean))` should work

Comment: For more dimensions `aggregate(VALUE~SIZR+COLOUR+COUNTRY  , dd, mean)` might be better but the shape of the output is different.